# como hacer una query dentro de un bucle con barios id en javascript, nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Hola buenos días espero que estén teniendo un bonito día lo que necesito el día de hoy es alguien que me ayude a encontrar la lógica para unas consulta, bueno procedo a explicar el siguiente código, vemos una consulta que me trae unos datos los cuales son las veces que se repite un, id de un usuario, pero necesito consultar los id de cada usuario mi idea es usar un bucle para hacer la consulta de los datos de cada usuario que me trajo para almacenarlos en una variable

el resultado de la query es el sigueinte: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora nesesito con el id_user_lender  una forma de consultar en otra tabla con cada id los datos y guardalos en una variable el resultado de cada consulta o query

````
                         if(error){
                             console.log(error)
                         }else{
                             console.log(results2)
                             const totalPrestamosPorUsuario = results2 
                             
                             for(let i = 0 ; i < results2.length ; i++){
                                  
                             }
                             
                             
                         }
                         
     
                     }) ```
````

Comment: En vez de consultar uno por uno, podrías hacer una consulta que incluya todos los `id`'s devueltos por la primera consulta.

Comment: Tal vez aqui encuentres la respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133084/how-to-access-rowdatapacket-mysql-node-js